# UI picker Trying to do it the right way

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipicker

I am trying to use a UI picker like a combo box in C#.  User clicks on a TextField, I have set the inputView to be the picker.  This works fine.  User clicks on the row and I get the item on that row and place it in the textfield.

However, when the application loads, this picker is visible!  I don't want it to be visible.  I want to be able to make it visible when the user clicks on the textbox and then when he or she moved off I want to hide it.  How do you do this?

Also , is it possible to have the picker only if the user wants to do a lookup like CTRL click.  Otherwise, it uses the keyboard?  How do you toggle back and forth between the keyboard and the picker.

For example suppose user wants to add a new book.  He/she clicks on the authors textfield and he/she either types the author ( a new author that does not exist in the database) or select and existing author from the list.

Thanks

Comment: Here you go
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275633/elegantly-replace-iphone-keyboard-with-uipickerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the inputView property of the textField. You can just set that to the picker and it should handle the rest for you.